# adftest function error in lagmatrix

Tags: matlab, runtime-error

Using the `adftest` function in MATLAB's econometrics toolbox, I'm receiving the following error:

```
>> [h1,pVal1] = adftest(y1,'model','ARD')
Error using lagmatrix (line 25)
lagmatrix: wrong # of input arguments

Error in adftest>runReg (line 705)
yLags = lagmatrix(y,0:(testLags+1));

Error in adftest (line 417)
        testReg = runReg(i,y,testT,testLags,testModel,needRegOut);
```

`y1` is a <41x1> vector of doubles.

Has anyone received this error or have any thoughts on what the issue is? I am using this code right out of the box so I'm not sure what is going on. I'd post to MATLAB's site, but it is down for maintenance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is either a bug in Matlab, in which case you should submit it on the [Matlab support site](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/). Before you do that, you should check that you don't have a function `lagmatrix` on your path that shadows the built-in function. Type

```
which lagmatrix
```

on the command line. If the path does not point to your Matlab installation, you should move `lagmatrix` off the Matlab search path.

Also note that `y1` should not contain all `NaN`, or be otherwise degenerate, so you may want to check the function using the sample data as suggested in the help to be sure it's a bug and not just your data.

Comment: Bravo, had `lagmatrix` on another path. I was looking for a command to tell me which function I was using too...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this function. In my case, the problem was the function `lagmatrix` (older version) in my MATLAB path and the `adftest` function was the newest version. The soluction was delete the older version of `lagmatrix`.